# How to Fullscreen pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I have a game that needs to be set in fullscreen. I am using the standard pygame.FULLSCREEN, when initializing the screen. It used to work, however when I updated to pygame 2.00, it no longer seems to work. I am using the code below, and before I get any information or the screen finished setting up it produces the error code:

```
pygame.error: Window surface is invalid, please call SDL_GetWindowSurface() to get a new surface
```

The code I am running is:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

controller = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
controller.init()

width = 600
height = 600 

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
pygame.display.init()


pygame.display.flip()
screen.fill((77,214,255))

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            running = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                running = False
```

If anybody knows of a solution to this problem, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Since i am not using pygame 2.0, I can not test it, but according to the documentation, you could try to set size to (0,0)... if using SDL 1.2.10 or above, it will try to adjust to the same size of the screen resolution. Can you give it a try? Apart from that, you are setting size to (600,600) and then asking for a fullscreen display... why is this? If you need your game to "believe" it is in a (600,600) resolution, but still be in a fullscreen mode, use also pygame.SCALE

Comment: Have you tried changing the width and the height to the exact resolution of your own display?

Answer (score 2):

Testing this on pygame 2.0.0.dev6, the code itself is working fine with no issues. However as others mentioned, it is better to set the width and height to 0 if you want the game to only open in full screen. Setting different measurements is redundant unless you use pygame.SCALED.

You can find more information [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode).

Comment: Thank you for the response? Do you have SDL installed, I would assume that it is needed for this to run properly?

Comment: yes I do, these are my specs: `pygame 2.0.0.dev6 (SDL 2.0.10, python 3.7.3)`.
SDL is indeed needed because it is a wrapper module for the SDL multimedia library

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is a bug in PyGame 2.0.0, the same happens to me. It seems that the version of SDL that is distributed with PyGame has some issues.

Try to use the system installed SDL2, e.g. by using LD_PRELOAD:

```sh
$ LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2.so python app.py
```

You can read more about the issue [here](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/2118).